# Replace variable read from a text file (so they can be interpreted)

Tags: linux, bash, files, text

I want to store in a text file some select statement that contain variables like a date:

```
$ cat res.txt
select field1, field2 from log and log_time~'"${TODAY}"*'
```

I want to use a script that will parse this file and for each statement, execute it. Of course, `${TODAY}` will be replaced with a variable.

Unfortunately, the `${TODAY}` is never replaced by a date when I read the file...

Is there a way to achieve this?

UPDATE:

Let say that I want to iterate through a file that containts some sql statements, and I want to execute them using psql (postgres)

Here is the file:

```
$cat sql.res
select path from log where log_host='toto' and log_time~'"${TODAY}"*' and log_msg='POLICY MISSING' and entry_status!='ACK' and path~'^/logs-${cli}/"${THREE_MONTHS_AGO}"_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9](_[0-9]{1,2}\.|\.)log(ptr|initial_ptr|account_ptr)?\.bz2$';
```

Now in a bash script, I want to:

```
$cat script.sh
TODAY=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
THREE_MONTHS_AGO=$(date -d "$TODAY -91 days" "+%Y-%m-%d")
THREE_MONTHS_AGO_2=$(date -d "$TODAY -92 days" "+%Y-%m-%d")
ONE_MONTH_AGO=$(date -d "$TODAY -36 days" "+%Y-%m-%d")
ONE_MONTH_AGO_2=$(date -d "$TODAY -37 days" "+%Y-%m-%d")
YESTERDAY=$(date -d "$TODAY -1 day" "+%Y-%m-%d")
while read item; do
    psql -P pager=off -t -c "$item" log | sed -e 's|^ *||' -e '/^$/d' > result.txt
done < sql.res
```

Unfortunately, the variables are not used in the script. So I have tried eval. I have like this:

```
$while read item; do
    c=$(echo $item | sed "s:':@:g" | sed "s:|:EE:g" | sed "s:(:AA:g" | sed "s:):BB:g" | sed 's:]{:TT:g' | sed 's|\.|OO|g')
    b=$(eval echo ${c} 2>&1)
    d=$(echo $b | sed "s:@:':g" | sed "s:EE:|:g" | sed "s:AA:(:g" | sed "s:BB:):g" | sed 's:TT:]{:g' | sed 's:OO:\\\.:g' )
    echo  "-> $b"
done < sql.res
```

But I have some issues with

```
\.
```

Comment: Execute it using what?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply replace the variable string with the value:

```
sed -e "s/\${TODAY}/$TODAY/g" res.txt
```

**But**:

- Be absolutely sure you have run the variable through a reliable (as in, created by the DB provided or part of a popular programming language API, *not* something homebrewed) *escape mechanism*.
- You'll also have to escape any characters *specific to `sed`* (and you can't just add backslashes before each character).
- You're using two levels of quotes, which you probably didn't intend.
- Please use a better language than Bash for this. It's horrendous for this kind of thing, because all the quoting and escaping business which complicates and makes it *really* easy to miss special cases. Python, Ruby and even PHP handle this sort of thing much better than Bash.

Comment: Thanks! I have also found this way, even if it is quite complex:

while read item; do TODAY="2012-03-28";c=$(echo $item | sed "s/'/@/g");b=$(eval echo "$c");d=$(echo $b | sed "s/\@/\'/g"); echo "-> $d";done < res
-> select field1, field2 from log and log_time~'2012-03-28*'

Maybe there could be some more efficient code but it seems to work.

Comment: Can you please put that code in the question (or a separate one), if it's relevant to the original question? It's quite hard to read in a comment. Also, [use more quotes](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html) :)

Comment: I agree with point 4, pick a better tool. A related discussion in [How to replace a list of placeholders in a text file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19970) mentions `cpp` and `m4`.